# Permisos de usuario en IOS

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Estoy haciendo una app que pide acceso para acceder a la galeria de imagenes. Por lo que tengo que pedir acceso al usuario.

Mi pregunta es:

Si el usuario la primera vez cancela los permisos, como puedo hacer para volverlos a pedir??

De momento tengo este código que me dice si los permisos están habilitados o no

```
if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
    //Están aceptados
}
else {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted :Bool) -> Void in
        if granted == true {
            //Los ha aceptado
        }
        else {
            //No los ha aceptado
        }
    })
}
```

Alguna posible solución??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, esta facil, en el else, agrega esto 
asi cada vez que el usuario quiera utilizar esa funcionalidad lo mandaras a cambiar la configuración, esto lo puedes meter en un alert view para que el usuario tenga la opción de ir a cambiar los ajustes o simplemente seguir sin utilizar la funcionalidad

```
let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
        print("Se abrieron las opciones")
      })
    }
}
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl!) {
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl!, completionHandler: { (success) in
          print("Se abrieron las opciones")
       })
   } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl!)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si ya lo has preguntado una vez, no va a volver a solicitarlo. El usuario tiene que ir a ajustes y darle permisos de acceso manualmente.

Comment: Y no hay ninguna forma de forzar a preguntar otra vez?? Para que usuario no tenga que volver a ajustes

Comment: No, no se puede. Siempre va a tener que hacerlo manualmente. Puedes poner una alerta que le indique que vaya a ajustes y le de permisos